# Node.js (sails.js) Find total number of files sent in a file upload

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, skipper

I have a file upload system in sails.js app. I want to process the uploads before saving them in the server. My form on the client side allows multiple file uploads. Now on the server side how do I know how many files were sent?

For example I can find the total bytes to be expected from the upload using the following:

```
req._fileparser.form.bytesExpected
```

However, I couldn't find something similar that helps me find the total number of files sent to the server.

Also the above code `req._fileparser.form.bytesExpected`, is there a better way to get total combined file size of the files sent through the upload form by the client?

Answer (score 5):

In the github repository for Skipper there is a file: [index.js](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper/blob/59a0c2704ff37de5a8ab47111e0e0822c072dde2/index.js)

Line 92 from the above file, which appears to deal with multipart file uploads, contains the following:

`var hasUpstreams = req._fileparser && req._fileparser.upstreams.length;`

You should check the length of upstreams in your code, and see if that contains the number of files you sent.

Another option: send a parameter in your request from the client with the number of files uploaded.

See the skipper ReadMe section about [Text Parameters](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper#text-parameters).

> Skipper allows you to access the other non-file metadata parameters (e.g "photoCaption" or
>   "commentId") in the conventional way. That includes url/JSON-encoded HTTP body parameters 
>   (req.body), querystring parameters (req.query), or "route" parameters (req.params); in other words, 
>   all the standard stuff sent in standard AJAX uploads or HTML form submissions. And helper methods 
>   like req.param() and req.allParams() work too.

I've just found a previous [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25627304/977424) on stackoverflow.

You might try using `var upload = req.file('file')._files[0].stream` to access and validate, as shown in the above answer.

Comment: Something similar to your first option is what I am looking for. But `upstreams.length` isn't giving me the right number of files sent for upload. Btw, if you are curious about what I want it for. I want to set max file size dynamically. For example if I allow 10 mb per file, and the user uploads more than 1 file at once, 10mb might not be enough. This is also the reason why I cannot trust the number sent as param by the client.

Comment: thanks for the stackoverflow link. It was good help. But I am still unable to get the total number of files received. The `headers` value only shows information about one of the files.