# How can I validate file type before upload use SailsJS Skipper

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, bluebird, skipper

As the title, now I can not check file type before upload. I only verify and don't allow save data after file uploaded successfully. Below is a basic code

```
updateAvatar : function(data, context, req, res) {
  req.file('avatar').upload({
      dirname: '../../assets/images/avatar'
    }, function (err, files) {

    var allowExts = ['image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg'];

    if (err)
      return res.serverError(err);

    if (files.length === 0) 
      return res.badRequest('No file was uploaded!');

    if (allowExts.indexOf(files[0].type) == -1)
      return res.badRequest('File type is not supported!');

    // save database here
  });
}
```

What should I do for correct code? 
Sorry for my bad English!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello, Did you find any solution?

Comment: @KrunalPanchal you can check out my answer to help your self

Answer (score 6):

This took me time to research on, all credits to [Darkstra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3560825/darkstra) who gave an idea of where we can get the raw file properties, like the content-type or even the file name, where we can split to get the file extension and do our checkings

you can check out his answer
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25627304/5836034)

The main thing is to take note of this

> `req.file('foo')._files[0].stream` which contains everything we need to handle our file, you can console.log it to see the content of it.

At least you can do any manipulation of your choice.

Comment: problem is that after calling req.file('foo') without uploading cause my app to crash Error: EMAXBUFFER