# how to split input file(image) stream in node js / sails js?

Tags: node.js, stream, sails.js, inputstream, node-streams

I want to split input stream into 2 stream. Because i am sending 2 image via file upload..

so in my controller i write like this

```
req.file('image')._files[0].stream
```

this contains details of 2 image. For example length shows sum of 2 images.

so what i want is soomething like below:

```
//calculate length of 1st image
var dataLength =0;        
req.file('image')._files[0].stream.on('data', function (chunk) {
    dataLength += chunk;
})
.on('end', function () {  // done
    console.log('The length of 1st was:', dataLength);
});

//calculate length of 2nd image
var dataLength2 =0;        
req.file('image')._files[0].stream.on('data', function (chunk) {
    dataLength2 += chunk;
})
.on('end', function () {  // done
    console.log('The length of 2nd was:', dataLength2);
});
```

what change should i made?
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [skipper](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper) package to handle multi upload

run this command in terminal

```
npm install skipper --save
```

at the top of your controller 
 `app.use(require('skipper')());`

now can use this package

```
req.file('image').upload({
  // ...any other options here...
}, ...);
```

Comment: I am already using skipper to upload file.. but i want to firstly check the size of both image & then upload the file.. please check out most voted answer of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25547101/sails-js-checking-stuff-before-uploading-files-to-mongodb-with-skipper-valid-fi). i am using same method. but i cant find solution for multiple files